# How to return IEnumerable list of objects with WebApi?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an object called PostMapDB and a method which retrieves a list of those objects. I would like to be able to pass this list and retrieve the data using webapi.

The code bellow gets me an error:`{"":["The input was not valid."]}`

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get(PostMapDB list)
{
    IEnumerable<PostMapDB> dataOfPosts = list.getAllPosts().OrderBy(x => x.Date);

    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataOfPosts, new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        {
            IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false
        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use POST and pass the data in request body

Answer (score 0):

How does your request to server looks like? 
What's the definition on PostMapDB?
Make sure you're passing data in a right way.
Probably the attribute FromBody would help:
`public string Get([FromBody] PostMapDB list)`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api